# Rolling unique count based on condition over last 31 days per day

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table orders with information regarding the time an onder was placed and who made that order.

```
   order_timestamp     user_id  
 -------------------- --------- 
  1-JAN-20 02.56.12        123  
  3-JAN-20 12.01.01        533  
  23-JAN-20 08.42.18       123  
  12-JAN-20 02.53.59       238  
  19-JAN-20 02.33.72        34
```

**Using this information, I would like to calculate on a per day basis, a count of distinct users who placed only one order in the previous 31 days, resulting in a table as**

```
    date      distinct_user_count  
 ----------- --------------------- 
  1-JAN-20                      8   
  2-JAN-20                     10  
  3-JAN-20                     11  
(i.e in the 31 days before and including 1st jan 2020, 8 unique users ordered only once, etc...)
```

Simply put, for every single day - 31, count the number of orders(entries in the table) for every user in that period , and if that count is only 1, count that user for the initial start date.

I can write the query to count those who ordered only once as:

```
with temp as (
  select 
    user_id,
    count(*) as order_count
  from 
    orders 
  where 
    trunc(order_timestamp) >= trunc(systimestamp - interval '31' day)
  group by 
    user_id
)
select 
  user_id, 
  order_count 
from 
  temp 
 where 
  login_count=1
```

but am unsure on how to implement the counting per date. Please can you assist in helping me to complete/write the query?  Thanks for supporting in advance.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use use two level of `grouping` and `self join` as follows:

```
Select dt, count(1) as cnt
  from
(Select distinct trunc(t1.order_timestamp) as dt, 
        t1.user_id
   From your_table t1
   join your_table t2
     On t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    And trunc(t2.order_timestamp) between trunc(t1.order_timestamp - interval '31' day) 
                                 and trunc(t1.order_timestamp)
 Group by t1.user_id, trunc(t1.order_timestamp)
 Having count(1) = 1)
Group by dt;
```

Or you can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
Select trunc(t1.order_timestamp),
       Count(1) as cnt
  From your_table t1
 Where not exists 
  (Select 1
     From your_table t2
     Where t1.rowid <> t2.row_id
       And t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
       And trunc(t2.order_timestamp) between trunc(t1.order_timestamp - interval '31' day) 
                                  and trunc(t1.order_timestamp)
Group by trunc(t1.order_timestamp)
```