# How to count no of days per user on a rolling basis in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, window-functions

Following on from a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62614918/rolling-unique-count-based-on-condition-over-last-31-days-per-day), in which i have a table called orders with information regarding the time an order was placed and who made that order.

```
   order_timestamp     user_id  
 -------------------- --------- 
  1-JUN-20 02.56.12        123  
  3-JUN-20 12.01.01        533  
  23-JUN-20 08.42.18       123  
  12-JUN-20 02.53.59       238  
  19-JUN-20 02.33.72        34
```

**I would like to calculate a daily rolling count of the number of days a user made an order in a past 10 days.**
For example, in the last 10 days from the 20th June, user 34 made an order on 5 of those days. Then in the last 10 days from the 21st June, user 34 made an order on 6 of those days

In the end the table should be like this:

```
    date      user_id   no_of_days  
 ----------- --------- ------------ 
  20-JUN-20        34            5  
  20-JUN-20       123           10  
  20-JUN-20       533            2  
  20-JUN-20       238            3  
  21-JUN-20        34            6  
  21-JUN-20       123           10
```

How would the query be written for this kind of analysis?
Please let me know if my question is unclear/more infor is required.
Thanks to you in advancement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions for this.  Start by getting one row per user per day.  And then use a rolling sum:

```
select day, user_id,
       count(*) over (partition by user_id range between interval '10' day preceding and current row)
from (select distinct trunc(order_timestamp) as day, user_id
      from t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a user places one order a day maximum, you can use window functions as follows:

```
select 
    t.*,
    count(*) over(partition by user_id order by trunc(order_timestamp) range 10 preceding) no_of_days
from mytable t
```

Otherwise, you can get the distinct orders per day first:

```
select 
    order_day,
    user_id,
    count(*) over(partition by user_id order by order_day range 10 preceding) no_of_days
from (select distinct trunc(order_timestamp) order_day, user_id from mytable) t
```